# Why I have access violation error when trying to put a pointer to an array as parameter of a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I got access violation error when i tried to iterate through the 'friday' array.

I tried to check for null pointers before the while loop but still...

```
int lostSheep(const int *friday, const int* saturday, int total)
{
    int friSum = 0;
    int satSum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(friday + i) {
        friSum += *(friday + i);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while(saturday + i) {
        satSum += *(saturday + i);
        i++;
    }

    int sum = satSum + friSum;
    return total - sum;
}

int main() {

    int array1[] = { 1, 2 };
    int array2[] = { 3, 4 };

    printf("%d", lostSheep(array1, array2, 15));

    return 0;
}
```

I just want to iterate through the array and sum all the elements

Comment: If `p` is a non-null pointer, `p + i` can't be a null pointer. There is no way to determine the end of an array when all you have is a pointer to one of its elements unless you write your own terminator in it (like the convention with strings).

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you! your comment helped me a lot!

Comment: `*(friday + i)` is more commonly written as `friday[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `while(friday + i) {` the test is never false even the first turn because *friday* is not a NULL pointer, so you access out of the array doing `*(friday + i);` when *i* is greater than 1

May be you wanted `while(friday[i] != 0) {` supposing you initialized *array1* with `{1, 2, 0}` ?

Of course there is a similar problem concerning *saturday*

Note you can also give the size of the array in parameter

It is more readable to use `friday[i]` rather than `*(friday + i)`

---

First possibility adding a null value to mark the end of the array :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lostSheep(const int *friday, const int* saturday, int total)
{
  int friSum = 0;
  int satSum = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while(friday[i]) {
    friSum += friday[i];
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  while(saturday[i]) {
    satSum += saturday[i];
    i++;
  }
  int sum = satSum + friSum;
  return total - sum;
}

int main() {
  int array1[] = { 1, 2, 0 };
  int array2[] = { 3, 4, 0 };

  printf("%d\n", lostSheep(array1, array2, 15));
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
5
```

---

Second possibility giving the size of the arrays :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int lostSheep(const int *friday, size_t sz1,
              const int* saturday, size_t sz2,
              int total)
{
  int friSum = 0;
  int satSum = 0;
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < sz1; ++i) {
    friSum += friday[i];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sz2; ++i) {
    satSum += saturday[i];
  }

  int sum = satSum + friSum;

  return total - sum;
}

int main() {
  int array1[] = { 1, 2 };
  int array2[] = { 3, 4 };

  printf("%d\n", lostSheep(array1, sizeof(array1)/sizeof(int),
                           array2, sizeof(array2)/sizeof(int),
                           15));
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
5
```

Under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==3996== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3996== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3996== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3996== Command: ./a.out
==3996== 
5
==3996== 
==3996== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3996==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3996==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==3996== 
==3996== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==3996== 
==3996== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3996== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
p
```

---

Note to have *friSum* and *satSum* separated to finally add them is complicated, to just have a unique *sum* is more simple, it is also possible to not have *sum* and directly decr *total*

```
int lostSheep(const int *friday, size_t sz1,
              const int* saturday, size_t sz2,
              int total)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < sz1; ++i) {
    total -= friday[i];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < sz2; ++i) {
    total -= saturday[i];
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: Or just pass the number of elements as parameters as well and loop with `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin agree, I edited my answer to speak about that

Comment: @bruno Thank you! you answered my question again!! I fix it to for loop and now it works!

Comment: @catify I edited my answer to give the two possibilities, you welcome